# C++ 11 array pass by reference without size in function

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I want to know Is there any way through which I can avoid mentioning size of array in function.  Below is my simple code. Every time I create an array in main I have to change size of reference array of function passbyref. 
Thanks alot.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<array>

using namespace std;

class GradeBook {
    public:

        void changevalues()
        {
            cout<<arr2[2]<<endl;
            arr2[2]=2;
            cout<<arr2[2]<<endl;
        }

        void passbyref(array<int,5>& refvar) //here 5 I have to mention myself
        {
            refvar[2]=2;
        }

    private:
        array <int,5> arr2;
};

int main() {

array <int,5> grades1{1,1,1,1,1};
GradeBook obj1;

cout<<"grades[2] before change =" <<grades1[2]<<endl;

obj1.passbyref(grades1);

cout<<"grades[2] after change =" <<grades1[2];



}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to switch to using std::vector.

Comment: Use a template parameter for the length, or `auto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates are your friends. The function below works with any array type that can be indexed with square brackets and has a value-type convertible to int.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<array>

using namespace std;

class GradeBook {
    public:

        void changevalues()
        {
            cout<<arr2[2]<<endl;
            arr2[2]=2;
            cout<<arr2[2]<<endl;
        }

        template<typename Arr>
        void passbyref(Arr& refvar) //here 5 I have to mention myself
        {
            auto N = distance(begin(refvar), end(refvar));
            cout << "size is " << N << '\n';
            refvar[2]=2;
        }

    private:
        array <int,5> arr2;
};

int main() {

array <int,5> grades1{1,1,1,1,1};
GradeBook obj1;

cout<<"grades[2] before change =" <<grades1[2]<<endl;

obj1.passbyref(grades1);

cout<<"grades[2] after change =" <<grades1[2];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 2):

The array size can be specified as a template parameter in `passbyref` function.

```
template <std::size_t N>
void passbyref(array<int,N>& refvar) {

}
```

The value of `N` will be deducted automatically, so there is no need to specify that in caller. In this way if you change the size in `main` there won't be any change needed in `passbyref`.

Comment: although note that this will compile into a separate instance of this function for every size of array that you use. If you are using more than a couple of sizes a vector may be more appropriate.

Comment: No need even to insist on std::array.

Comment: "Deducted." Har har.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better for you to use a *dynamic array* - one whose length can change at runtime. The easiest way to work with dynamic arrays is using the [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which manages an array internally.

```
void passbyref(std::vector<int>& refvar) // no need to mention size
{
    if(refvar.size() > 2)
        refvar[2] = 2;
}

// ...

int main() {

    std::vector<int> grades1 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}; // any length you want

    passbyref(grades1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of `std::array` is that the size is an integral part of a specific array as is the type, which makes it cleaner than the c-style array, but it means that in functions, the expected size must be present.

Possible solutions:

- templates, but is `std::array` the correct container then?
- typedef (or using): `typedef std::array<int,5> MySpecificArray`
- `std::vector`

Answer (score -1):

`<rant: on>`That's a common problem in C++: there is no way to declare a sequential container for which the size is constant and only known at run time. That's one of the reasons (along with C compatibility) while some compilers notably gcc and clang allow Variable Length Arrays in C++ as a compiler extension.`<rant: off>`. If only a few sizes will be used and will be compile time expressions, you can use a template integer value for the size (`std::array<int, sz>`). In any other case you will have to rely on `std::vector` for a C++ conformant way.

Comment: vla doesn't solve this though, it works only in statement closure and is essentially a syntax sugar for allocating array in dynamic memory.

Comment: @Swift: no. VLA is the only way for a function to properly declare an array for which the size is only known at run-time and is the only way to cleanly pass a multi-dimensional array. The C++ idiom (vector or vector) if really far from a 2D (rectangular) array and make mix language programming (C++ and Fortran for example) harder

Comment: I know latter bit clearly, i did not meant . I meant, that declared array is created in heap (no other way to implement that). If we have size N as variable, then  `int a[N];` with VLA   is equivalent of `int *a = new int[N]` and respective delete at end of scope. multidimensinal arrays passed as as addresses to beginning of such area, index math is implied by compiler